# iOS8 Animate Transform Not Working As Expected

Tags: ios, xcode, jquery-animate, transform

I had a beautiful zoom animation that was working perfectly up until iOS8.  Now it seems to 'jump' to halfway through the animation and it looks terrible.  The code was quite simple...

```
// zoom in on this focus kanji
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
    // zoom in
    newFocusSentence.transform = [self getZoomTransformForKanji:thisKanji];
```

So I'm pretty sure there's nothing wrong with it.  The zoom ends up in the right place, but doesn't seem to start from the right place.  The fact that it ends up in the eight place and was working before leads me to believe that the transform itself is fine.  Is anyone else seeing bad results with animating transforms?

Thanks
Ray

Comment: Well, turns out this is indeed an iOS8 bug.  I submitted a report with a test project, but they closed it as a duplicate.  At least it's on their radar.  Hopefully it'll make it into an update soon.